# Automapper returns only Matched property values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Here I am using automapper class to match "userdetails" class to "FinalizedDetails" class. I have tried but I am getting only the last name value but for NameFirst and BooksInfo it returns nothing. How to fix this issue i am strange to automapper. 
I didn't understand the complete usage of Automapper class.

**HomeController:**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     UserDetails objDao = setData();
     Mapper.CreateMap<UserDetails, FinalizedDetails>();
     FinalizedDetails objDetails =  Mapper.Map<UserDetails,FinalizedDetails >(objDao);
     return View(objDetails);
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(string id)
 {
     return View();
 }
 private UserDetails setData()
 {
     UserDetails daoObj = new UserDetails();
     daoObj.FirstName = "Mike";
     daoObj.LastName = "Castillo";
     daoObj.Salary = 6000;
     daoObj.Certified = true;
     daoObj.BookDetails = new Books();
     daoObj.BookDetails.BookName = "Auto Mapper Tuts";
     daoObj.BookDetails.BookPrice = 200;
     daoObj.BookDetails.BookDescription = "A brief Description about Automapper class";
     return daoObj;
 }
```

**Index.cshtml :**

```
@model AutoMapper_Demo.Models.FinalizedDetails
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
    @Html.TextBox("First anme");
    <p>First name : @Model.FirstName</p>
    <p>Last Name : @Model.LastName</p>
    <p>BookInfo : @Model.BooksInfo</p>
```

**Models :**

```
public class UserDetails
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string getFullName()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public bool Certified { get; set; }
    public Books BookDetails { get; set; }
}
public class Books
{
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public int BookPrice { get; set; }
    public string BookDescription { get; set; }
}
public class FinalizedDetails
{
    public string NameFirst { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string BooksInfo { get; set; }
}
```

**Output**

```
First name : 

Last Name : Castillo

BookInfo :
```

Comment: This part: `<p>First name : @Model.FirstName</p>` - I don't see a `FirstName` in your `FinalizedDetails` which you're using as a model.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov yeah I just changed the name of the First name to NameFirst, Actually I thought that the auto mapper will automatically maps the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automapper won't map properties that don't have matching names automatically (in fact it has no way of knowing how to this), however you can specify that by yourself:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDetails, FinalizedDetails>()
      .ForMember(d => d.NameFirst, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.FirstName));
```

**EDIT**

Since you've asked how you'd map the `BookInfo`, and presuming that you want some sort of a summary you can do (for example) the following:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDetails, FinalizedDetails>()
      .ForMember(d => d.NameFirst, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.FirstName))
      .ForMember(d => d.BooksInfo,
                 o =>
                 o.MapFrom(
                     s => string.Format("{0} - ({1})", s.BookDetails.BookName, s.BookDetails.BookDescription)));
```

Comment: How to get values for BookInfo

Comment: @Vignesh What is `BookInfo` supposed to map to ? (Book Name, Book Price, Book Description) ?